# How can I build a collection type with multidimensional wildcard indexing to return multiple matches?

Tags: dictionary, collections, f#, binary-search-tree, wildcard

I apologize if the question title is confusing; feel free to suggest an alternative.

I am writing some data analysis code and I have a set of data that I want to construct a map with, which can be used to look up certain keys to find certain values. But I want to be able to use a wild card for parts of the multidimensional key so that multiple values are returned. I also want fast lookup and efficient memory use.

My key is 5 dimensional. If I didn't want to be able to use wild cards in the lookup, then the solution is simply to use a 5 dimensional tuple for the key of a Map. Sometimes I do only want to return a single value using a fully specified key, but other times I want to return an aggregation of the results for a partially specified key. The value I am storing is a 3 dimensional tuple of floats.

If I didn’t want efficient memory usage, then I would create a 5 dimensional array and create 5 index lookups (one for each part of the key) then wrap the whole this with appropriate accessor methods. To get all values where one of the key parts is a wild card, simply access the array with ‘0..’, then aggregate the results as desired. In this case, much of the array will be empty. It doesn’t seem like a good idea because I don’t know in advance how big each dimension will be so the cross product could be beyond what is possible.
The solution I have gone with for now is just to have separate maps for each kind of look up I am interested in. For instance, if my full key is k1*k2*k3*k4*k5, and part of my code wants to access aggregated data for anything that matches k1***k3*k4** then I will create a map indexed by k1*k3*k4 that stores the aggregated float it cares about. The number of combinations is rather large (32 * 3 = 96, I think) so if I wanted the ability to access this data in every possible way using the method I have gone with, I would need 96 different maps and accessor methods.

As I get to the end of writing this I realise that there must be a way of doing it because databases manage this problem just fine. How do they do it and can I do the same in F# in memory?

Comment: Have you looked into using a structure like a [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)?

Comment: @TheInnerLight never hear of it until now. Certainly sounds like the right thing. Hopefully I can find a package rather than trying to implement it myself.

Comment: If you don't find something, I will try to give you a rundown of how to implement it but it might be a day or two before I have time to do that. What type are the keys of each dimension out of interest, i.e. what is the type of `k1`?

Comment: TradeDate (DateTime) * SecurityID (string) * PortID (string) * TradeType (6 case union) * IDType (5 case union)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses nested dictionaries. I haven't done any benchmarking, but at least it doesn't need a "full table search" as long as all keys are not wildcards. Note that I replaced the union types with integers here.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type MultidimensionalIndex<'T>() =

    let data = Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, 'T>>>>>()

    let getOrAddEmpty key (d : Dictionary<_,_>) =
        match d.TryGetValue key with
        | true, innerDict -> innerDict
        | false, _ ->
            let innerDict = Dictionary<_,_>()
            d.[key] <- innerDict
            innerDict

    let selectValues keyOpt (dicts : Dictionary<_,_> array) =
        dicts
        |> Array.collect (fun d ->
            match keyOpt with
            | Some key ->
                match d.TryGetValue key with
                | true, v -> [| v |]
                | false, _ -> [||]
            | None ->
                Seq.toArray(d.Values))

    member __.Add (k1, k2, k3, k4, k5) value =
        let innermostDict =
            data
            |> getOrAddEmpty k1
            |> getOrAddEmpty k2
            |> getOrAddEmpty k3
            |> getOrAddEmpty k4
        innermostDict.[k5] <- value

    // None represents a wildcard
    member __.Query (k1Opt, k2Opt, k3Opt, k4Opt, k5Opt) =
        [| data |]
        |> selectValues k1Opt
        |> selectValues k2Opt
        |> selectValues k3Opt
        |> selectValues k4Opt
        |> selectValues k5Opt
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty good idea. Now I am wondering why I didn't think of it myself! Let me do some testing and if all goes well, I will accept this as the answer.